# onTextChanged prevet space / new line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to do something and it is does not work: I am trying to prevent a space key writing into the editText and it is does not prevent that, I`m trying to do this by this code:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if((addressTextBox.getText().toString().contains(" "))) {
        return;
    }
}
```

How can I do this to prevent new line too (ascii char number 10) ?

Comment: This question has been raised before. Please check properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **new line** just add `android:singleLine="true"` for your "EditText" in the xml file

For the blank space use (as he said **@AKSiddique** in his answer)

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         ed.setText(result);
         ed.setSelection(result.length());
         // alert the user
    }
}
```

Give it a try and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as usually much simpler

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if(addressTextBox.isFocused()){
    if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
         // alert the user
}
    }
}
```

Comment: It`s shows that I can`t resolve 3 symbols:
1.editText1
2.ed
3.result
so a replaced ed with my edittext name like this:

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (editText1.isFocused()) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                    addressTextBox.setText(result);
                    addressTextBox.setSelection(result.length());
                    // alert the user
                }
            }
        }

and now i cant resolve 2 symbols:
1.editText1
2.result